# What are the dimensions of the State Alchemist pocket watch?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, cosplay

I want to cosplay as Roy Mustang for Halloween but as I was looking at the costumes online I noticed the cosplay pocket watches are tiny! The biggest one is 5cm. But in the anime, they look like a full palm-sized pocket watch. I was wondering if anyone knows the actual dimensions of the State Alchemist pocket watch?

Comment: I doubt they ever give the actual dimensions of the State Alchemist watches, but from a cursory search of the internet, 5cm would be a fairly normal-sized pocket watch, particularly if it's for the entire thing (case and all). Normal measurements are done of the movement, which is the thing inside the case, and ~40mm seems normal for that.

Comment: Official licensed product: https://www.amazon.com/Fullmetal-Alchemist-Brotherhood-Necklace-Accessories/dp/B005CFO8RE

Answer (score 1):

Here are some images of the watch as it appears in the hands of various characters, this should give you an idea of the size of watch you want:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image]